# how to use temporary table in procedure, Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

i have a temporary table

```
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_location
   (
      city VARCHAR(30),
      street VARCHAR(30)
   ) 
   ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

and i want to use this table in my procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fexample(
    pcity character varying)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
BEGIN

    select * from temp_location where city = pcity;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100;
```

this method working in oracle, but not in postgresql

Comment: That will not work in Oracle. Oracle - just like Postgres - needs the result of a query to be stored somewhere. You can't just write a select statement in a stored procedure in Oracle or Postgres. You need to do _something_ with that data. Either return it, or store the column values in local variables.

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fexample(pcity VARCHAR(30))
  RETURNS TABLE(c VARCHAR(30),a VARCHAR(30)) AS
$$
    select * from temp_location where city = pcity;
$$
  LANGUAGE sql;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=8d8c32bafb9c60997c52835f84a5b9f8)**

Comment: no, i must use in procedure. for example loop etc.

 for c in (select q.* from temp_location q)loop
 
 end loop;

Comment: @piscu: if you just want to return the data, this is the way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Unless I missed the boat, I think you want something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fexample(pcity character varying)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  rw temp_location%rowtype;
BEGIN

    for rw in select * from temp_location where city = pcity
    loop
       -- do stuff with rw
    next rw;

end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100;
```

If you declare the rowtype as a variable, you can then consume it within the query.

Comment: your code does not working because postgresql doesn't calling  temporary table in procedure

Comment: @piscu: you are wrong, that code will work just fine in Postgres.